# Should I pre-allocate an array or grow as I go

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, v8

I have been trying to understand javascript better over the last few months. This has definitely made me want to get a Computer Science Degree. Anyways, I have sadly run into two related but conflicting points in relation to JavaScript.

According to [this article](https://thibaultlaurens.github.io/javascript/2013/04/29/how-the-v8-engine-works/), one should not prefill an array, but instead grow it when need be.

That sounded great and all, until I run into another [article on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array#Bounded-size_dynamic_arrays_and_capacity) that stated that doing the above would be slow.

I am thinking of putting together some games from scratch, and being the code vegan that I am, plan on putting performance at the for front of my efforts. **So is it better to have an array that grows or one that is pre-allocated?** In HTML5 game development it is advised to use things such as object pools, which I tend to create using an array.

Comment: Don't prefill arrays in JS, let the interpreter take care of that for you. The wikipedia article is discussing very low-level tradeoffs of how best to handle dynamic arrays, all of which JS will take care of for you

Comment: Note also that pre-filling and pre-allocating are two different things.

Comment: @Hamms can you please elaborate.

Comment: pre-allocating means initializing an array with room for as many things as you want: `new Array(arrayLength)`. pre-filling means initializing an array and then also filling it with values: `new Array(arrayLength).fill(initialValue)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Rough guidelines:

One that is pre-allocated is better. If you grow one with for instance `push` or `pop` the JS engine needs to do a lot of additinal steps.

Even using an oversized array is way better than changing the size often. And you should operate on fixed size arrays whenever you can.

[Here](https://gamealchemist.wordpress.com/2013/05/01/lets-get-those-javascript-arrays-to-work-fast/) you can find more information regarding this.

### Aray performance is Highly based on JS engine implementation:

Because javascript is a specification not an implementatation different browsers have different versions of the Javascript engine. These versions are updated regularly to enhance speed and take different approaches on how to optimize this.

When optimizing there are often tradeoffs between the speed of certain features including how arrays are manipulated/created. This means that the guidelines that I provided above might not be 100% accurate because one JS engine can have certain behaviour which the other JS engine lacks. This can cause differences in speed of manipulation/creation techniques on arrays.

Comment: Man! Thank you, I have been looking for that article (the one by gamealchemist) for ages. Definitely a great read, and it should make more sense now that I have a better understanding of js

Comment: Note that most of the claims in this article are quite subjective; the JS language spec does _not_ mandate the time or memory complexity of any of the operations the author is testing, so results are going to vary dramatically by runtime environment.

Comment: @Hamms  I was about to green tick this answer, but you making me doubt so much.

Comment: I think this one was for V8, but you are right. Different JS implementations have different performances for different tasks based on how they are implemented. However, there are some  'guidelines'

Comment: For example, their https://jsperf.com/push-allocated-vs-dynamic test does indeed run as they claim on firefox, but on Chrome `push` is just as performant as the other methods

Comment: But yes, I read about that on stackoverflow, apparently that is also why it is difficult to do array related performance tests (or to find them reliable that is). But what do you think, if I was working on a game, would it be better to use Prefilled or just grow.

Comment: The answer to that is going to be very situational. Every situation is going to be different, and every browser or other runtime environment is also going to be different. Additionally, it depends on whether you want to optimize for memory considerations or computational considerations in each situation

Comment: @WillemvanderVeen please can you elaborate.

Comment: @Hamms I actually run that jsperf and found that pre-allocating is faster. i use chrome. I also noticed that the reverse counting is faster? Which contradicts what the article linked above states: computers don't like reading backwards (point number 3).

Comment: Exactly; the results are going to vary a _lot_ because none of the statements the article makes are backed up by the JS spec itself; the article is making claims that are specific to the state of Chrome's implementation of JS in 2013

Comment: I wouldn't agree with the whole article, judging from the current data, but somethings do match up. Pre-allocating followed by a pre-fill (using a while loop that isn't in reverse though), use integer[] over any[], etc.

Comment: The reverse iteration should not be taken as gospel though. There are times where you'll want to go backward through an array (e.g., removing elements from an array rather than creating a new array with `filter`). As @Hamms seems to be saying, performance is very context-sensitive. Any article claiming that "this way is always the best way in all situations" is lying to you.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thank you for your comment, I am aware of this, but a little reminder never hurts anyone. Still have to learn how to use filter effeciently. I have been trying to avoid it.

Comment: @WillemvanderVeen Could you please update your answer so that I can green tick it. I don't feel right not giving you the reputation, but I also cannot ignore the fact that there is some crucial information missing in your answer.

Comment: Updated it to reflect the difference between JS engines and the uncertainty accompanied with it.